# ListView item highlighting

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, virtualization, listviewitem

I am designing a code viewer using a virtualized ListView control to display code lines.

Now I want to create a highlight effect when the user clicks a link which takes them to a particular line. I want the target line to be highlighted.

The effect will be either an "underline" appearing (and disappearing) or a semi-transparent overlay (like a marker pen) appearing (and disappearing). The actual graphical effect itself is unimportant, that's not the problem.

What is the best approach to achieve this? I'm not quite sure where to start.

Some technical requirements *might* be that I need to:

- find the right events to react to - or use databinding
- obtain the absolute bounding rectangle of the virtualized target item (although when brought into view the item should be available)
- absolutely position a canvas effect on top, fade in and fade out

...Ideally some state changes in a view model, a piece of XAML is animated via a triggered storyboard to appear (fade in) above the relevant ListViewItem and then animates away again (fade out). Of course before the fade in, the element must already be correctly positioned over the relevant ListViewItem...

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on a search feature for a Listview where every ListViewItem had few textbocks. When the user types something in a search textbox, all the matches in the listview was supposed to get highlighted.

I created Run objects based on the search string (used Regex to find the match) and then set the Background to some color. Also, held the reference of the ListViewItem in the tag of the Run object which helped me to use call ScrollIntoView. Hope this will be of some help in your case.